# __radd__() method with Numpy Array as other, the Numpy Array was passed one by one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a class (`MyClass`) with an attribute `data` which is a Numpy Array. I would like to allow operations such as :

```
myclass3 = myclass1 + myclass2   
myclass3 = myclass1 + Numpy.ndarray  
myclass3 = Numpy.ndarray + myclass1
```

where all these operations add the data together and return a new MyClass. So the first two are easy using by defining **add**(). But for the last case, it behaved not as I expected that the ndarray passes the element one by one of sum with `myclass1.data`.

This is what I mean.

```
import numpy as np
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        print(other)
        if isinstance(other, MyClass):
            data = self.data + other.data
        else:
            data = self.data + other
        return MyClass(data)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        print(other)
        data = self.data + other
        return MyClass(data)

myclass1 = MyClass(np.arange(5))
myclass2 = MyClass(np.ones(5)) 
nparray = np.arange(5) + 10
alist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

In all the addition combination, they are all fine even `alist + myclass1`, but `nparray + myclass1` returns:

```
In __radd__: 10
In __radd__: 11
In __radd__: 12
In __radd__: 13
In __radd__: 14
```

What happened was that each element of the Numpy Array was passed into **radd** one by one rather than as a whole. And it returns five times, and I got the `res` as `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` rather than `MyClass` object.

So how can I allow `Numpy.ndarray + MyClass` operation where the entire ndarray will pass in as other in **radd**().

Best regards, 
J

Comment: Why dont you inherit from ndarray?

Comment: That could work just for the sake of __rdd__(), but I am afraid this will get too messy.  Also that will be a constructor needs to be inline with ndarray, and that will involve so major API changes. For the package which is already released, I think that is overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about it. `alist + myclass1` fails, so it calls your `__radd__` function, which works as intended. But, in `nparray + myclass1`, numpy tries to avoid failure by broadcasting. So, it will do the equivalent of

```py
for value in nparray.data:
    value + myclass
```

which will fail each time, and *only then* your `__radd__` will be called.

Comment: So is there away to prevent users from doing nparray + myclass1 by raising an exception? It is not encouraged in my case anyway because I am dealing with audio data, so nparray + myclass1 is dangerous without knowing the sampling rate of the nparray. However, I don't want to simply raise an exception at __radd__() because int + myclass1 is a legit case I would like to have.

Comment: @J_yang: no, broadcasting is automatic, and it's invoked before left-add fails. In the right-add, you can't know whether the int you got is a stand-alone argument or it comes from numpy broadcasting an array. Only way would be inheriting from np.array (which is not simple, there's too much magic going on in that class)

Comment: It might be possible to detect if you're being called with a scalar value and return `NotImplemented` in that situation (assuming you don't want to support `1 + myclass`). I imagine at some point numpy will give up on broadcasting and let the top-level Python code try to call the `__radd__` method itself.

Comment: @Blckknght: he wants to support `1 + myclass`, that's the problem. Numpy is built on broadcasting to a large extend, in most cases it's beneficial, this is collateral damage. Removing it is veeery unlikely

Comment: @Blckknght blue_note is right. I would sacrifice that in order to keep 1 + myclass which has legitimate use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer is wrong. You actually can achieve this by defining `__array_ufunc__` on `MyClass`.

See this NEP: https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html#nep18

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35718221)